# vuejs: mounted issues with coordinates of elements and svg

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have three columns, two with divs and the central one with an svg. I made a method that calculate the top() of each paragraph

inside the divs to get the position and then draw an arrow in the svg. The problem is that when I use that method the first time I open my component, I get all zeroes, probably because the paragraph aren't really drawn (they have no coordinates) yet. I tried in mounted(), which should be the right place to do that. I use it also in updated() in case I reload my json with new data.
Am I missing something trivial?

The code I use to get the coordinates is like this:

```
drawLine(index1, index2) {
      //var plist1 = this.$refs['p_list1'];
      //var plist2 = this.$refs['p_list2'];
      var plist1 = document.getElementsByClassName('p_list1');
      var plist2 = document.getElementsByClassName('p_list2');
      if (plist1.length == 0 && plist2.length == 0) return;
      var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
      //...
      //const start = this.$refs['startpos'].getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const start = document.getElementById('startpos').getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const r1 = plist1[index1].getBoundingClientRect();
      const r2 = plist2[index2].getBoundingClientRect();
```

index1 and index2 comes from a loop where I get which paragraph I have to connect with an arrow (also where the nextThick is)

Here is a simple example of the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-vue-test-bcozc
Note: it's badly shown, but if you press "DO" and then switch tab, you'll see that the arrow aren't correct. If you switch tab and then press DO, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding that the problem was linked to how tabs are built, I tried making that specific tab lazy and it worked.

```
<b-tab lazy ...
```

I don't know how tabs are normally built, but I suppose the dom is put together without having a real coordinate system and when it's made visible, I don't have any event to read to update the svg.

Answer (score 1):

Put your calculation methods in a `$nextTick` function to allow parents and children to fully render.

If that does not work, as a debug step, try using a `setTimeout` method to delay the calculation.

Comment: I tried both method in mounted() and updated() but got always positions 0,0

Comment: to rule out  vue issues, try id instead of ref, and getElementById.  not sure where index1 and index2 are coming from, either.

Comment: I did modify with getElementById and getElement/ByClassName for the list of Ps. Still the same issue. Don't worry about index1/2 since it's just a number that defines which element to get from the list. Any element shouldn't be at 0,0.

Comment: you are going to need to post a reproducible snippet.

Comment: I made a simple example. It seems the problem is linked with the way I load the data + tabs

Comment: Please check the original question. I've added the example at the bottom. Apologies for the ugliness, but the idea is there. Data Load is simulated with the "Do" button.